# Integrating MVC4 with WebForms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, routes, integrate

I'm trying to integrate MVC4 with WebForms.
The webforms projects are separated into two different solutions.

1. Solution 1: Projects P1 and P2 on Asp.Net 4.0 framework
2. Solution 2: Projects P3 and P4 upgraded to Asp.Net 4.5.1 and maintain 4.5.1 dlls

There's already a HomeController file in project P1 in solution 1 and I have added another HomeController in P3 in solution 2. After successful build, I'm unable to access the HomeController in P3. I get, resource cannot be found error. Also, when I attach debugger, in P3 - HomeController, I get following message on debug point:

"This breakpoint will not currently be hit. A copy of HomeController was found in P3.dll....."

However, the entire website flow is working properly. I have followed quite a few blogs to integrate MVC with webforms like

http://www.codebureau.com/asp-net/integrating-asp-net-mvc-into-an-existing-asp-net-webforms-application/

http://blogs.ibs.com/Scott.Zischerk/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe just changing the startup project to `P3`?

Comment: Not sure because our start up project is set to P1 since it has login page and other rules